# Error while Saving pandas dataframe to msql database

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table in pandas dataframe  df.

[image]

i want to write this to database. so i am using df.to_sql, but getting error.
i am using MySQLdb.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="1xx.xxx.x.xxx", user="uname", passwd="123", db="dbname")
cursor = conn.cursor()

df.to_sql(con=conn, name='table_name', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

but i am getting error :`OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

any insights/solutions to why this is happening? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are passing a wrong variable. Are you sure that you are passing strings to MySQL instead of lists?

EDIT: I think you can try like this

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

col1 = 123, 676, 93
col2 = 3245, 35346, 32
frequency = 2, 84, 9

dataset = list(zip(col1,col2,frequency))

df = pd.DataFrame(data = dataset, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'frequency'])

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo=False)
df.to_sql(name='sample_table2', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

You need to install sqlalchemy (`pip install sqlalchemy`) and you have to download the sqlconnector from [mysql website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

Tell me if you need something else.

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: Can you post an example of your dataframe?

Comment: Can you try to change this 
`df.to_sql(con=conn, name='table_name', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')`

Comment: Nope, sorry... I need some examples

Comment: I've tried, the only error that I have is the incompatibility with mysqldb and dataframe.to_sql. Have you tried with SQLAlchemy also? It's supported by dataframe.to_sql.

Comment: no,i've no idea about SQLAlchemy. can you please paste a code snippet for me sir